# How to search the specific text from the files in Magnolia?

Tags: magnolia

I am not able to search the text directly from the Search Box of Magnolia Admin-central.

For Example I need to search specific style(class names.. etc) from the css files which are available in App STK/Resources/Themes/css. How can we do it directly?

Magnolia Version :5.3.9.

Is it available for Latest versions of Magnolia?

Thanks,
Vijay Kodali.

Answer (score 1):

[image: css search]

Seems to work just fine for me. ("textColor" is inside of the using-freemarker.css file) Double check that you don't have any error in the logs or that your index is not corrupted. AFAIK you can search only for whole words not partial text.

HTH,
Jan

Comment: Yes, you are right. its working for me too with complete word. Thanks Jan